# Adding vspace between x-axis label and legend generated with legend to name feature

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, positioning, legend

I recently started working with pgfplots and now I am trying to generate two horizontally aligned plots using the same data. So I wanted to use one single, centered legend for both plots. It is all pretty basic and the description given in the pgfplots manual fits my needs almost perfectly. The only problem is, as stated in the title above, that with the x-axis labels and the label of the figure environment, everything looks a little bit cramped. I tried to add some `\vspace` between `\end{tikzpicture}` and `\ref{named}`, but this only pushes down the figure label. Is there any way to add some space between the x-axis label and the legend entries?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[
legend columns=-1,
legend entries={GDR C016,GDR K01174,WA C016},
legend to name=legende,
    width=0.48\textwidth,
    height=0.6\textwidth,
    grid=major,
    xlabel={Concentration[ng/mL]},
    minor x tick num=1,
    ylabel={Remission [CU]},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=250,
    minor y tick num=1]
\addplot[mark=*,blue] plot coordinates {
    (0.0,196.5)(0.1,182.3)(0.2,173.1)(0.5,116.7)(1.0,47.7)};
\addplot[mark=*,red] plot coordinates {
    (0.0,151.5)(0.1,131.5)(0.2,114.5)(0.5,77.6)(1.0,34.7)};
\addplot[mark=*,olive] plot coordinates {
    (0.0,232.5)(0.1,123.1)(0.2,63.7)(0.5,33.9)(1.0,23.9)};
\fill[gray,fill opacity=0.2] (axis cs:-0.1,150) rectangle (axis  cs:1.1,200);
\fill[green,fill opacity=0.2] (axis cs:-0.1,0) rectangle (axis cs:1.1,30);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
%
\hskip 10pt
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}[
    width=0.48\textwidth,
    height=0.6\textwidth,
    grid=major,
    xlabel={Concentration [ng/mL]},
    minor x tick num=1,
    ylabel={Displacement [\%]},
    ymin=0,
    ymax=110,
    minor y tick num=1]
\addplot[mark=*,blue] plot coordinates {
    (0.0,100)(0.1,92.8)(0.2,88.1)(0.5,59.4)(1.0,24.3)};
\addplot[mark=*,red] plot coordinates {
    (0.0,100)(0.1,86.8)(0.2,75.6)(0.5,51.2)(1.0,22.9)};
\addplot[mark=*,olive] plot coordinates {
    (0.0,100)(0.1,52.9)(0.2,27.4)(0.5,14.6)(1.0,10.3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\ref{legende}

\caption{Verschiedene Polyhaptene im Schnelltest}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't fully understand, if I take the example on page 216 of the manual and add some `\vspace` where you suggest, the legend is pushed down. Can you add a complete, working example to your question)?

Comment: Thank you for your quick and kind reply. I added my working example. I already tried to move the command to other areas of my code but without satisfiying results...

Comment: Ok, wow, now I feel completely confused. I ran the WE on my notebook now and it works. On my PC, nothing. Same document, same TeX-Editor, same packages... Feeling pretty stupid.

Comment: You can delete the question if you want.